# How to extract an element from an array (in an array?) within a Json into Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to set up a Pokemon spread sheet and don't want to enter lots of data points.

Would like help either solving problem, or if I could be directed where to look to teach myself that would also be really helpful.

Trying to get individual data points out of what i think is called an array in within a JSON (clearly little experience), and input them into Google Sheets.

In my example the aim is to get the base_stat of speed extracted

Below is the end of the JSON(of some 10k lines);  https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/

The data point we want to extract is on line 3, but I wasn't sure how much else was valuable.

```
    "stats": [
{
  "base_stat": 45,
  "effort": 0,
  "stat": {
    "name": "speed",
    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/6/"
  }
},
{
  "base_stat": 65,
  "effort": 0,
  "stat": {
    "name": "special-defense",
    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/5/"
  }
},
{
  "base_stat": 65,
  "effort": 1,
  "stat": {
    "name": "special-attack",
    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/4/"
  }
},
{
  "base_stat": 49,
  "effort": 0,
  "stat": {
    "name": "defense",
    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/3/"
  }
},
{
  "base_stat": 49,
  "effort": 0,
  "stat": {
    "name": "attack",
    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/2/"
  }
},
{
  "base_stat": 45,
  "effort": 0,
  "stat": {
    "name": "hp",
    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/1/"
  }
}
  ],
  "types": [
    {
      "slot": 2,
      "type": {
        "name": "poison",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/4/"
      }
    },
    {
      "slot": 1,
      "type": {
        "name": "grass",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/12/"
      }
    }
  ],
  "weight": 69
}
```

so when the JSON doesn't have the square brackets I have had success retrieving data with code like

```
function GETSPEED(Name) {
  var myUrl = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/" + Name;
  var jsonData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(myUrl);
  var jsonString = jsonData.getContentText();
  var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  var Value = (jsonObject.speed)
  return Value;
}
```

Have deduced that I have two problems;

1) "Value = (jsonObject.speed)" the .speed isn't separated by a colon from my wanted answer and therefore my eventual ask is the wrong thing.

2) What I'm requesting on the line before still holds many elements (arrays?)

For part 1 'base_stat' is repeated alot and I dont know how to differentiate.
For part 2 I dont know where to start.

I've had a good google around for an answer to this, or a place to start learning and didnt find any point on which to build.

Anyway thank you in advance for any help rendered or time spent reading this.

Comment: `jsonObject['stats'][0]['base_stat']`

Comment: Works a dream, now can do everything I wanted to. Cheers muchly